# Fixing div to top of page when reaches top of screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to fix a sidebar to the page when the div reaches the top of the page. I've got the following code (see below) and it's working.. Kind of... it doesn't add the class at the correct position? Does anyone know what im doing wrong?

Link to the page: http://www.bluemoontesting.co.uk/bluemoon2016/people.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var s = $(".timeline");
    var pos = s.position();                    
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
            s.addClass("timeline-fixed");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("timeline-fixed"); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what's the correct position you want to?

Comment: What is going wrong? If I go to your page there's definietly an element getting fixed to my screen

Comment: It is but it's happening before the div has reached the top of the page. I'm not sure if it's to do with the fonts loading before hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below jquery snippet. This will make the element with the class '.wrapper' to follow scroll, meaning it will always be on the top of the page. In your case you may need to tweak the offset.

```
var nav = $('.wrapper');
        var navHomeY = nav.offset().top;
        var isFixed = false;
        var $w = $(window);
        $w.scroll(function() {
          var scrollTop = $w.scrollTop();
          var shouldBeFixed = scrollTop > navHomeY;
          if (shouldBeFixed && !isFixed) {
            nav.css({
              position: 'fixed',
              top: 0,
              left: nav.offset().left,
              width: nav.width()
            });
            isFixed = true;
          }
          else if (!shouldBeFixed && isFixed)
          {
            nav.css({
              position: 'static'
            });
            isFixed = false;
          }
        });
```

Comment: Hey man, i've added that but it's still fixing the element before it's reached the top.

Comment: In your site.. bear in mind that the element 'timeline' has a margin top thay may complex the things

Comment: JmRag - the margin was what was causing the problem. Many thanks :)

Comment: If my answer help you, then mark it ! You are welcome